# SQL Server Convert Timestamp DataType to Decimal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Been Trying to figure this out and according to Cast and Convert Documentation on MSDN, this should be possible (
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx )

Have a look at the Conversion table.

[image]

I am running the following Code:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (
    ID bigint Identity(1,1),
    SomeValue nvarchar(20) not null,
    TimestampColumn timestamp not null)

Insert Into TableName (SomeValue)
values ('testing')

SELECT Convert(decimal, TimeStampColumn) from TableName
```

However I simply get the following error:

> Error converting data type timestamp to numeric.

This should be possible according to the documentation or am I missing something?
Note I will also need to convert back to the same timestamp value.

```
SELECT TimeStampColumn, Convert(timestamp, Convert(decimal, TimeStampColumn)) 
FROM TableName
```

In the end the above query should render the same value.

Comment: You should also consider asking this on [dba.se] - Advanced querying, database internals, database design, and all other data-related questions are on topic there and the signal-to-noise ratio is very high.

Comment: I initially thought this was precision/scale related but it is not from my testing.  I don't use `timestamp` but I'm curious about the cause.

Comment: @JNK  I thought the same thing.  But it does not matter what precision/scale you enter.   Binary is also suppose to convert to decimal which timestamp is essentially a binary(8)

Comment: @JohnHartsock your question is generating interest and perhaps a bit of confusion. Would you mind updating us with the table definition?

Comment: @swasheck updated the question with the table definition and an insert statement.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHartsock. Wanna [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap)?

Comment: It seems the truth to this question is that the MSDN documentation is not accurate. There is not an implicit conversion from timestamp to decimal (or numeric) and back. The most promising workaround is provided by Rahul.

Comment: Would you like this migrated to our database Q&A site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this; though MSDN says it's a implicit conversion but it actually doesn't work. So, what I am doing is converting it to INT and then to decimal (INT to decimal is implicit anyways)

```
select val, CAST((CONVERT(bigint, timestampcol)) as decimal) as 'TS as decimal' 
from teststmp
```

Comment: OP needs to convert to `DECIMAL` directly to handle values beyond the scale of `int` or `bigint`

Comment: @JNK - Why? `timestamp` is only 8 bytes (same as bigint)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you can assign positive values beyond the scale of `bigint` to a timestamp, can you not?  I'm definitely not an expert on `Timestamp`.

Comment: Note Int cannot hold a full timestamp, since timestamp represents a binary(8) its value range can be from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: @JohnHartsock - [So same as `bigint` then](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

Comment: @JNK - [Had a bit of a play with timestamp here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11088/3690). I might try hacking the database boot page to put `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` and see how it reacts when generating the next one (e.g. does it roll over)

Comment: @JohnHartsock, in your case since it's a non nullable field ... it will be binary(8) (8 bytes size) which is same as bigint (8 bytes size).So, in my post .. instead of converting it to int .. I will convert to bigint. Edited ...

Comment: @Rahul yep was talking in "the Heap" with other and we came to the same conclusion. + 1  best work around given.

Comment: @JohnHartsock - Not sure what you are using this for but my testing indicates that it is actually treated as an unsigned 64 bit integer rather than signed as `bigint` is. So the `timestamp` allocated after `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` is then `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808`

Comment: @Martin Smith - thank you for correcting this. It's sad the accepted answer is flat out wrong and I have to scroll the comments to find out.

Answer (score 5):

This is a safer way I think.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN Cast(timestampcol AS BIGINT) >= 0 THEN 
         Cast(timestampcol AS BIGINT) 
         ELSE 18446744073709551615 + Cast(timestampcol AS BIGINT)
       END
```

The following shows that otherwise the straight forward cast to bigint will wrap around to negative numbers which likely isn't the desired result.

```
USE tempdb;

IF DB_ID('TestDBTS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE TestDBTS;

CREATE DATABASE TestDBTS;


USE TestDBTS;

SELECT CAST(CAST(@@DBTS AS BIGINT) AS DECIMAL(20,0))
/*2000*/

/*Hack to manually set the timestamp. Undocumented, Unguaranteed & Dangerous!
  Do not use except on test databases.*/
DBCC WRITEPAGE(TestDBTS, 1, 9, 412, 8, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F);


ALTER DATABASE TestDBTS SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

ALTER DATABASE TestDBTS SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

USE TestDBTS;
SELECT CAST(CAST(@@DBTS AS BIGINT) AS DECIMAL(20,0))
/*9223372036854775807*/

CREATE TABLE T
(
X INT,
Y TIMESTAMP
)

INSERT INTO T(X) VALUES(1)

SELECT CAST(CAST(@@DBTS AS BIGINT) AS DECIMAL(20,0))
/*-9223372036854775807*/

SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(@@DBTS AS BIGINT) >= 0 
            THEN CAST(@@DBTS AS BIGINT)
            ELSE 18446744073709551615 + CAST(@@DBTS AS BIGINT) 
       END
/*9223372036854775808*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal, TimeStampColumn + 0)
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Wouldn't that implicitly convert to an `INT`?

Comment: Close but still not there.  I cant convert back to the same timestamp value.